# View SQL data from CRM into Sharepoint 2010 BCS failing

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sql-server

I'm trying to view CRM Customer data from the SQL database in SharePoint so that I can use it in surveys etc.

I followed these instructions (amongst others) http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/integrating-dynamics-crm-data-into-sharepoint-2010/ and am having no joy. I've got the list page to show up but there is no data showing.

In SharePoint Designer when creating the Read List and Read Views I get the following error.

"This operation type can modify data in the data source. The data source element statecode is not nullable in the data source. Mark this data source element as a field in the operation."

I've no idea what this means. If anyone could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken your error simply states that a certain field (which does not allow NULL) have to be also added during the configuration of your BDC Model (most likely in the Read Item). Make sure you are not missing any of the Key fields in your selection.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: I have an accountid field picked, which has null set to false. For now I'm only trying to get the first name and last name to display, but can't get around this error.

Comment: I just ended up using another field with the null value as false. All working now. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped!